# Get and set values from a UITextfield in a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have 4 text fields in cells. When I enter a value in some of them, I will call a method and then need to display some data in another text field. I have 3 rows of cells. Currently only the values for the last row are coming correctly.

```
    { 
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        cell.qntityTxt.tag=indexPath.row;

        [cell.qntityTxt addTarget:self action:@selector(totalCalc:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];


        return cell;
    }

    - (void)totalCalc:(UITextField*)txtfield
    {
        int total,price,qty;
          NSLog(@"Tag value %ld",(long)txtfield.tag);
            price=[cell.priceTxt.text intValue];
            qty=[cell.qntityTxt.text  intValue];
            total=price*qty;

            Total=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];
        cell.totlTxt.text=Total;

        [_addPdtTblVw reloadData];

    }

    [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: How did you get cell in totalcalc method?

Comment: I got solution
- (void)totalCalc:(UITextField*)txtfield
{
    int total,price,qty;
      NSLog(@"Tag value %ld",(long)txtfield.tag);
    
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection: 0];
        
        cell = [_addPdtTblVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        
        UITextField *TextProduct= (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:8];

Comment: UITextField *TextPrice= (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:9];
        UITextField *TextQuantity= (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
       UITextField *TextTotal= (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];
 NSLog(@"TextProduct mthd :%@",TextProduct.text);
        NSLog(@"TextPrice mthd :%@",TextPrice.text);
        NSLog(@"TextQuantity :%@",TextQuantity.text);
        NSLog(@"TextTotal mthd :%@",TextTotal.text);
        
        price=[TextPrice.text intValue];
        qty=[TextQuantity.text  intValue];
        total=price*qty;

Comment: Total=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];
        cell.totlTxt.text=Total;
 }
    [_addPdtTblVw reloadData];
    
}

Comment: @lj999 Please don't post code in comments. Either [edit] your question if you have more details to add or post an actual answer if you solved your own issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is same as what you commented!!

```
    (void)totalCalc:(UITextField*)txtfield { 
    int total,price,qty;
     NSLog(@"Tag value %ld",(long)txtfield.tag); 
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){ 
    NSIndexPath indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection: 0];
    cell = [_addPdtTblVw cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *TextProduct= (UITextField)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:8];
    UITextField *TextPrice= (UITextField)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:9];
    UITextField *TextQuantity= (UITextField)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    UITextField *TextTotal= (UITextField)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];
    price=[TextPrice.text intValue];
    qty=[TextQuantity.text intValue];
    total=price*qty;
    Total=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",total];
    cell.totlTxt.text=Total; 
    }
    [_addPdtTblVw reloadData];
    }
```

Comment: i got this exception

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView priceTxt]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb862d0d9e0'

Comment: did u got solution or not?? you wrote something in your comment!!

Comment: yes i found solution by myself. When i put your code it is giving exception

Comment: Do you want my solution then i will work on it? Your Wish :)

Comment: yes i know.. wait then! working on it! Do you wish to update all the textfield  of all cell's??

Comment: no. only need to update last cell "total cell". After entering pricing and quantity, total value automatically need to load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137838/discussion-between-lj999-and-nikdange-me).